# Android Espresso: checking if a TextView is showing a formatted string from resource

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-resources

Suppose you have a **formatted** string like this:

```
<string name="saving">You saved %1$s with %2$s</string>
```

now if you want to check if your TextView is showing it correctly, so naturally, something like this would work:

```
 Espresso.onView(withId(R.id.tv))
            .check(matches(withText(R.string.saving)))
```

but it doesn't and I cannot check the text with hardcoded strings because it might be on another language. so is there even a way for that?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe something like:

```
Espresso.onView(withId(R.id.tv))
        .perform(object :ViewAction{
            override fun getDescription(): String {
                return "Normalizing the string"
            }

            override fun getConstraints(): Matcher<View> {
                return isAssignableFrom(TextView::class.java)
            }

            override fun perform(uiController: UiController?, view: View?) {
                val tv = view as TextView
                if (tv.text.matches(Regex("You saved (.)*? with (.)*"))) {
                    tv.text = "You saved %1\$s with %2\$s"
                }
            }
        }).check(matches(withText(R.string.saving)))
```

Comment: Your solution, while it works, but it cannot be used with different languages :/

Comment: Why shouldn't it work? It is a regex. It works with any character. Do you have an example to demonstrate what you stated?

Comment: @AminKeshavarzian This is a demo of the regex with 3 different languages. Persian, English and Swedish characters: https://regex101.com/r/zvvktU/2